# How to make sure that timed out request was not carried out? ios

Tags: ios, timeout

Hey I'm developing an iOS application which communicates with an external web service in order to make various kinds of requests.

I'm aware of Murphy's Law "Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong" and that made me think about timeouts. Currently my application does not handle the situation when a request get completed and times out simultaneously. How should I handle such situations?

Comment: Show network code and situation described in code.

Comment: Surely you would need to re-confirm with the server till you don't get a timeout on the confirmation...

Comment: Reconfirm how? Repeat a request to pay a million dollars?

Comment: @djna If the request was a POST and created a resource, an agent should be able to subsequently construct a corresponding GET request which returns the URL of the created resource (or an error), even when the session ended. Uhps, reading your answer :) never mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without cooperation from the service provider there's not a lot you can do. If your app sees a timeout it cannot from that deduce whether the request actually completed or not. Could be it worked and something in the infrastructure failed to deliver the response, could be that it failed and hence you saw no timely response.

You have some actions you can take that will help the user. I assume that you have available to you the details of the request you attempted to send, your app should keep that locally. You are now in a position to do some useful things:

Some service authors allow you to safely submit the same request twice. So just resubmit, if it previously worked the service will just say "yep, already done that, here's the details|, if not it will just do the work as normal.

Some service authors allow you to query the status of previous request, so you can determine what has been done and what has not.

In some cases there is no IT system way to deal with the problem, the user will need to contact a help desk or call centre. Here having the details of what was previously attempted can be very useful.